# CSS custom tooltip font awesome image disappearing

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS which displays a font awesome image before certain text based on the element name, and also underlines that text.  This is to encourage the user to hover over for more explanation.

```
x-help {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f00;
}

x-help::before {
        content: "\f059";
        font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
        text-decoration: inherit;
        padding-right: 0.5em;
        position: relative;
    }
```

I also have the following CSS that displays a custom tooltip on hovering and all this works great except when the original text is hovered over the font awesome image disappears.

```
x-help{
    position: relative;
}

    x-help::before {
        content: attr(data-title);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -35px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 4px 10px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

What magic can I add to the CSS to prevent this from happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are resetting the ::before content. You can use ::after instead.

I changed only following to make it work rest of the css remains the same.

```
x-help:hover::after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -35px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fj5swmpr/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the icon in the x-help tag. Here is a demo.

```
<x-help data-title="Hello world"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> Hover over me and the bell unfortunately vanishes</x-help>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rLayfjem/

Comment: Thanks but that won't work in our situation because sometimes we need to content of the page to be displayed without the underline and FA image, and the easy way on those pages is to simply not include the links to the CSS.

Using your method will permanently display the FA image unfortunately.

Comment: You can hide on hovering the icon if you want using x-help:hover i {display:none;}

Comment: Thank you but that still wouldnt work in our use-case. Have accepted Jatinder's answer now but appreciate your help.